# Fibonacci series by recursive function in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello I am trying to generate Fibonacci series by using a recursive function in python.

Here is my code

```
def fibolist(n):
    list1 = [1, 1]
    if n in (1,2) :
        return list1
    else:
        fibolist(n-1).append(sum(fibolist(n-1)[n-3:]))
        return list1
```

but when I enter any number as an argument, the result is `[1, 1]`
Could you please help me?!

Comment: Try this... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494594/how-to-write-the-fibonacci-sequence

Comment: I would recommend reading the follow article: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: You never update list1, so it will always be [1,1]. Even when you recursively call fibolist, you need to change list1 or do something with it and return that value.

Answer (score 2):

You start with

```
list1 = [1, 1]
```

You never change that value, and then you return it to the calling routine.

Each invocation of `fibolist` has a local variable named `list1`; appending to one does *not* change the `list1` value in the calling program.  You need to explicitly do that.  Try

```
else:
    return fibolist(n-1) + [sum(fibolist(n-1)[n-3:])]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, It was a big help! :)

Answer (score 1):

Just to fix your code:

```py
def fibolist(n):
    if n in (0,1) :
        return [1,1]
    else:
        return fibolist(n-1)+[sum(fibolist(n-1)[n-2:])]
```

Few notes:

lists in python have starting index=0, so it's better start with it (unless you want to put start return to `[0,1,1]` for `n in (1,2)`).

Also - as already mentioned you shouldn't return local variable, which you preassign in each go.

Comment: Thank you very much, It was a big help! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not updating the list1 variable that it returns upon coming back from the recursion. Doing `fibolist(n-1).append(...)` updates the list returned by the next level but that is a separate list so `list1` is not affected.

You could also make your function much simpler by making it pass the last two values to itself:

```
def fibo(n,a=1,b=1): return [a] if n==1 else [a] + fibo(n-1,b,a+b)
```

BTW, the modern interpretation of the fibonacci sequence starts at 0,1 not 1,1 so the above signature should be `def fibo(n,a=0,b=1)`.

Output:

```
print(fibo(5))
#[1, 1, 2, 3, 5]
```